# Mapping keyword with a dataframe column using pandas in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe,

```
DF,
Name    Stage   Description
Sri     1       Sri is one of the good singer in this two
        2       Thanks for reading
Ram     1       Ram is one of the good cricket player
ganesh  1       good driver
```

and a list,

```
my_list=["one"]

 I tried mask=df["Description"].str.contains('|'.join(my_list),na=False)
```

but it gives,

```
 output_DF.
Name    Stage   Description
Sri     1       Sri is one of the good singer in this two
Ram     1       Ram is one of the good cricket player

My desired output is,
desired_DF,
Name    Stage   Description
Sri     1       Sri is one of the good singer in this two
        2       Thanks for reading
Ram     1       Ram is one of the good cricket player
```

It has to consider the stage column, I want all the rows associated with the description.

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: no, mask=df["Description"].str.contains(my_list,na=False) works good but I want to pick the other row too. until the stage is finished or again the stage is 1

Comment: My pc is hanging ill restart and answer, give me some time.

Comment: Is possible match data by `Name` column?

Comment: no, see in stage =2 , name column is null

Comment: Then my solution should be simplify - instead `df['Name'] = df['Name'].mask(df['Name'].str.strip() == '').ffill()` -> `df['Name'] = df['Name'].ffill()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df)
     Name  Stage                                Description
0     Sri      1  Sri is one of the good singer in this two
1              2                         Thanks for reading
2     Ram      1      Ram is one of the good cricket player
3  ganesh      1                                good driver

#replace empty or whitespaces by previous value
df['Name'] = df['Name'].mask(df['Name'].str.strip() == '').ffill()
print (df)
     Name  Stage                                Description
0     Sri      1  Sri is one of the good singer in this two
1     Sri      2                         Thanks for reading
2     Ram      1      Ram is one of the good cricket player
3  ganesh      1                                good driver

#get all names by condition
my_list = ["one"]
names=df.loc[df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False), 'Name']
print (names)
0    Sri
2    Ram
Name: Name, dtype: object

#select all rows contains names
df = df[df['Name'].isin(names)]
print (df)
  Name  Stage                                Description
0  Sri      1  Sri is one of the good singer in this two
1  Sri      2                         Thanks for reading
2  Ram      1      Ram is one of the good cricket player
```

Comment: IF we have, 

my_list ["Thanks"], it gives me "Thanks for reading" row. But i dont want to map when the stage is other than 1. Is there a way ?

Comment: I want to map my_list and df["Description"] only when the stage is 1. if we find a match we will get all the stages for the particular description.

Comment: Yes, I think instead `df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False)` need `df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False) & (df['Stage'] == 1)`

Comment: do you want to replace this 

      
      
      
 **names=df.loc[df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False), 'Name']**

if i did I am getting only the columns, no values are there

Comment: Yes, exactly. Need chain new condition.

Comment: ok I got it, If we changed we are getting the rows which are having stage=1.

Comment: For condition we need to map with df["Description"] when the stage=1. if we find a map we need to consider stage =2 also for the same description

Comment: Yes, `names=df.loc[df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False) & (df['Stage'] == 1), 'Name']` return nothing for `my_list = ["Thanks"]`, because `Thanks` is in stage 2 only.

Comment: yes Jezrael, it works fine. I dint check properly. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I want to add the keyword "one " in a new column in the final dataframe,

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be finding "one" in the Description fields of the dataframe and returning the matching descriptions.

If you want the third row, you will have to add an array element for the second match

eg.  'Thanks'    so something like  my_list=["one", "Thanks"]