# Mapping keywords with a dataframe columns using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe,

```
DF,
Name    Stage   Description
Sri     1       Sri is one of the good singer in this two
        2       Thanks for reading
Ram     1       Ram is one of the good cricket player
ganesh  1       good driver
```

and a list,

```
my_list=["one","driver"]

I tried, names=df.loc[df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False), 'Name']
```

achieved everything except the keyvalue column.

```
 output_DF.
Name    Stage   Description
Sri     1       Sri is one of the good singer in this two
Ram     1       Ram is one of the good cricket player

My desired output is,
desired_DF,
Name    Stage   Description                                 keyvalue
Sri     1       Sri is one of the good singer in this two    one
        2       Thanks for reading                           
Ram     1       Ram is one of the good cricket player        one
ganesh  1       good driver                                  driver
```

some one help me with generating keyvalue column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use previous solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46559618/2901002) and then [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
pat = "|".join(my_list)

df['keyvalue'] = df['Description'].str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False).fillna('')
print (df)
     Name  Stage                                Description keyvalue
0     Sri      1  Sri is one of the good singer in this two      one
1     Sri      2                         Thanks for reading         
2     Ram      1      Ram is one of the good cricket player      one
3  ganesh      1                                good driver   driver
```

All together:

```
print (df)
#     Name  Stage                                Description
#0     Sri      1  Sri is one of the good singer in this two
#1              2                         Thanks for reading
#2     Ram      1      Ram is one of the good cricket player
#3  ganesh      1                            good Driver one

my_list=["ONE","driver"]
df['Name'] = df['Name'].mask(df['Name'].str.strip() == '').ffill()

pat = "|".join(my_list).lower()

names=df.loc[df["Description"].str.lower().str.contains(pat,na=False), 'Name']

df = df[df['Name'].isin(names)]

df['keyvalue'] = (df['Description'].str.lower()
                                   .str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False)
                                   .fillna(''))
print (df)
#     Name  Stage                                Description keyvalue
#0     Sri      1  Sri is one of the good singer in this two      one
#1     Sri      2                         Thanks for reading         
#2     Ram      1      Ram is one of the good cricket player      one
#3  ganesh      1                            good Driver one   driver
```

Comment: no Jezrael, i dont want to add "one" for all the rows. It has to add the exact matching keyword

Comment: ops, give me some time.

Comment: Edited the final expected output, please check

Comment: What is 2 or more values match?

Comment: we can give the first value

Comment: It is not working if the Description column has the value with higher case,
If the Description has  uppercase value "ONE" and my_list has lower case "one"
then value is not printing in keyvalue column

Comment: are you there           ?

Comment: Sorry, I have idea. Use parameter `re.IGNORECASE` in `extract` - but I dont test it yet.

Comment: str.extract("(" + pat + ')',re.IGNORECASE,expand=False) is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now I am going test it.

Comment: I test it now, need `df['keyvalue'] = df['Description'].str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE).fillna('')`

Comment: And then if need all values lowercase `df['keyvalue'] = df['Description'].str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE).fillna('').str.lower()`

Comment: It is working for the my sample data, but for my actual data its not working. something is wrong, ill check

Comment: If it does not work, solution is all convert to lowercase and then test like `pat = "|".join(my_list).lower()` and then `df['keyvalue'] = df['Description'].str.lower().str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False).fillna('')`

Comment: I want to edit this code

names=df.loc[df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False), 'Name']

to 

I want to map the lower cases of df["Description"] with my list

so I tried

* names=df.loc[df["Description"].str.lower().str.contains("|".join(my_list),na=False), 'Name'] * but I am getting empty df, can you check

Comment: Hmmm, it should work. I test it now and for me it working perfectly.

Comment: with sample data, sure.